# C++: Prevent method from expanding too early when passed as argument

Tags: c++, format, parameter-pack

I attempt to write a basic logger that should pass any message to the shell and a log file (for now, both write to `std::out`) using `std::vformat`. For that, i created a wrapper `log_message()`:

```cpp
template <typename ...P>
void log_message(std::string_view format, P&& ...params) {
    m_do_colors = false;
    std::cout << "Writing to file, flag is " << m_do_colors << std::endl;
    log_message_to_file(format, params...);

    m_do_colors = true;
    std::cout << "Writing to shell, flag is " << m_do_colors << std::endl;
    log_message_to_shell(format, params...);
};

template <typename ...P>
void log_message_to_shell(std::string_view format, P&& ...params) {
    std::string msg = std::vformat(format, std::make_format_args(params...));
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
};

template <typename ...P>
void log_message_to_file(Severity severity, std::string_view format, P&& ...params) {
    std::string msg = std::vformat(format, std::make_format_args(params...));
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
};
```

I also have a function that puts ANSI color tags around a string:

```cpp
bool m_do_colors = true;

std::string color_str(std::string str, int color) {
    std::cout << "colorizing string: " << m_do_colors << std::endl;
    if ( m_do_colors == true ) {
        return std::format("\033[0;{}m{}\033[0;m", color, str);
    } else {
        return str;
    };
};
```

the purpose of the `m_do_color` variable should be to "disable" colorizing a string whenever the message is passed to the file output, but "enable" colors when output is shell.

An example for a use case with `logger.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <format>

class Logger {
  /** (((stuff from above))) **/
}
```

and `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "logger.h"

int main() {
    Logger log;
    log.log_message(log.INFO, "This is a {}", log.color_str("Test", 45));
    return 0;
}
```

what is printed is

```
colorizing string: 1
Writing to file, flag is 0
This is a Test
Writing to shell, flag is 1
This is a Test
```

with "Test" having coloured background both times. The output idicates that all arguments of the `log_message()` function are expanded before the function's body is expanded.

What I *want* to get is this:

```
Writing to file, flag is 0
colorizing string: 0
This is a Test
Writing to shell, flag is 1
colorizing string: 1
This is a Test
```

with only the second "Test" being coloured.

How can I prevent the `color_str()` method from "expanding too early"? Is there a way to tell the compiler that the arguments of `log_message()` should only be expanded *inside*  its body, not beforehand?

I already tried with "regular" `std::format()` and also passing the arguments on with `std::forward`, but the result is always the same.

Comment: Functions aren't "expanded". They are either called immediately, or you pass a pointer or other callable object so it can be called at a later time. Lambdas could be useful here, especially lambdas (or functions) that return a lambda that can be called later.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm a bit lost. Do I need to alter the call to `color_str()` in the `main()` function or is there a way to keep that as-is and do the magic inside the class's definitions somewhere?

Comment: @Lupino what he is talking about it passing a function that your logging code will call, similar to `log.log_message(log.INFO, "This is a {}", []{return log.color_str("Test", 45);});`. C++17 added `std::is_invocable<>`, which should allow your template to figure out whether an argument is like that, so your template implementation can call it to obtain the string. Which, unfortunately, doesn't directly work with `std::format` so you'll have to roll something yourself -- but when you do that, you could integrate the coloring on that level and not do those callback functions at all.